# How can I take JSON file from ElasticSearch using pyspark?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark

I'm new on pyspark... I was wondering if it could be possible to **get JSON source file from ElasticSearch (based in localhost:9200) using pyspark library on Jupyter Notebook**... How can I do this?

Comment: es data (json) to spark

Comment: via Elasticsearch for Hadoop: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-data-sources